# Mac Pro 5,1 (Mid-2010) not seeing airport card with Mojave

Tags: mojave, airport, mac-pro

So, this is very strange:  I have a drive with Mountain Lion on it, and when I boot that drive, I have WiFi (using the installed Airport card).  I just made a clean install of Mojave and when I boot onto that drive the WiFi icon is grayed out and when I click on it, it says "no WiFi installed?"

How is it that WiFi works on Mountain Lion, but not on Mojave?

Comment: Did you, by any chance/replace change the AirPort card so that you're not using the original?  It should work as the [Mid-2010 is supported in Mojave](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777)

Comment: This is an original airport card I had bought back in 2008 for my Mac Pro 3,1, which I later upgraded to a 5,1..  Is it possible that the original airport card is not compatible with their modern OSes, and I would need to find a newer airport card?

Comment: So, technically, it’s a 3,1 MacPro which isn’t compatible with Mojave. Like you upgraded the CPU, FPU, etc. you’re going to need to upgrade the AirPort card to a 5,1 version so Mojave drivers will be available for it.

Comment: no I mean, I sold my mac pro 3,1 and got a 5,1 and kept my airport card...